# Challenge working with Visual Studio and VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have started working with C++ recently and am not comfortable with Visual Studio Development Environment and also I do not have proper understanding of MFC, Win32, ATL, COM Terminologies.

From example point of view, I had taken a simple C++ program to see how it works with Visual Studio Environment and I was having some issues to get that code up and running.

I would like to request if someone could point me to some online resources/books where I can get more understanding about Visual Studio Development Environment from C++ perspective and get some knowledge about MFC, Win32, ATL, COM Terminologies than it would be really very helpful to me.

Note: I have checked MSDN library and some related Microsoft sites but when I see HOW DO I kind of video tutorials they are more from .Net/C#/ASP.Net perspective but I am looking for some online resource for C++/VC++ perspective.

Comment: @Stackoverflow Readers: I would like to request if someone could point me to some online resources/books where I can get more understanding about Visual Studio Development Environment from C++ perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic book about Win32 is presumably [Petzold's](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/). Petzold's book is I think (I've never read it) mostly about GUI programming; whereas the other classic/recommended Win32 book, which is [Richter's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240), is about 'system' (non-GUI) programming.

For learning COM, perhaps [Essential COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465)? Some reviewers praise it, but some others reviews say things like "not for beginners"; but it's how I learned COM, and I found it thorough, low-level, and detailed. It assumes you know C++ (not COM) already.

IMO you don't need books about MFC if you already know C++ and the Win32 API, in which case the [reference libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.80).aspx) are sufficient. Alternatively, some people recommend an MFC book like [Prosise's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950).

Comment: @ChrisW: Thank you very much Chris for the detailed answer. I am very much interested in learning about Visual Studio Development Environment from C++ perspective and so what would be the online resources/books that you would strongly recommend to me. 

Again, I would like to thank you for all your valuable inputs and it really guides well and helps a lot. 


Thank you ChrisW :)

Comment: I don't know what online resources there are for beginners; the first place I search is MSDN, so http://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com+visual+studio+c%2B%2B

Comment: @ChrisW: Thank you Chris for the information. It provides some information that I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) of course will have plenty of resources around if you look @ the right tags

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com

etc.

[The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) is also a good resource for windows / C++ programming, here are a couple areas to start looking @:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/
- [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx](http://codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx) (via [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49046/andy) in comments)

Comment: @TJB:Thank you very much for your valuable inputs, it really helps. Actually I am looking for Visual Studio Development Environment from C++ perspective and so what would be the online resources/books that you would strongly recommend.

Also thank you very much for all the information you have provided. It really guides and helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I learned using Visual Studio IDE and MFC using the Scribble Tutorial. It was a step-by-step tutorial creating a simple MFC application. Unfortunately the tutorial was written for Visual Studio 6.0, and in the meantime almost all wizards and menus changed, so it's not applicable anymore.

The tutorial can be found in MSDN, here, though:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716528(VS.60).aspx

The scribble sample source for Visual Studio 2008 can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts.aspx

Comment: @vividos: I am willing to learn about Visual Studio Development Environment from C++ perspective, are there any good online resources/books that you would strongly like to recommend. 

I really appreciate all the information you have provided and it is really very very useful. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother learning ATL, WTL, MFC or COM for now (or at all, really). Just use standard C++ for starters. If you want to write GUI programs, [I recommend Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/developer), it is much easier and fun to use than any of the former APIs.

If you have trouble compiling Qt for Visual C++ you can download the entire Qt SDK and it comes with a C++ IDE called Qt Creator. It uses MinGW as a backend.

Comment: @rpg: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs. I am looking for Visual Studio Development Environment Tutorial from C++ perspective and so what would be the online resources/books that you would strongly like to recommend. 

Thank you very much for your valuable guidance and it really helps.